# Find unique lines based on only a section

Tags: shell, pipe, input

I am wondering if there is a way to split lines by some character (E.g. `:`) and find unique lines based on one part of this split.

For example if I had the following piped in via `stdin`

```
file1: line 4
file1: line 5
file1: line 6
file2: line 1
file2: line 2
file2: line 1
file53: line 67
file24: line 412
```

Is there a way I can extract only one line per file, for instance:

```
file1: line 4
file2: line 1
file53: line 67
file24: line 412
```

Or even better:

```
file1
file2
file53
file24
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Cut -d: -f1 | sort -u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with a couple of common utilities:

```
cut -d : -f 1 input.txt | uniq
```

- `cut` extracts fields from the input file. `-d` denotes the delimiter character (in this case a `:`), and `-f 1` says to extract the first field.
- `uniq` removes repeated adjacent lines from the input

Answer (score 0):

Since all of my results had the same format (The file's were in the `src/` directory) I was able to use the following command:

`cat input.txt | tr ':' '\n' | grep 'src/' | uniq`